# mongodb golang limit results by date

Tags: mongodb, date, go

I have a mongodb collection that I am trying to limit the result set, but the data was created by someone else and the date format appears to be stored as "2016-05-12 00:00:00.000Z".  I am unsure how to format my find query to limit this type of date.  I have been successful with other types of date formats, but not this one.  Has anyone else encountered this issue?

```
myCollection {
  "_id" : {
    "$oid" : bson.ObjectId
  },
  "createdDate" : {
    "$date" : Date
}
```

This is what I have attempted.

```
toDate := time.Date(time.Now().Year(), time.Now().Month(), time.Now().Day(), 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
fromDate := toDate.AddDate(0, 0, -1)

collectionResult := collectionRecords.Find(bson.M{"retailer": result.Id, "createdAt": bson.M{"$gte": fromDate}})
```

Ultimately, I would like to limit to one day and was attempting to do the following:

```
collectionResult := collectionRecords.Find(bson.M{"retailer": result.Id, "createdAt": bson.M{"$gte": fromDate, "$lt": toDate}})
collectionResult.All(&collectionData)
collectionCount, _ := collectionResult.Count()
fmt.Println("Count: ", collectionCount)
```

it always returns 0.  Like I stated above I have been successful with UTC dates, but this one seems to trouble me.

Comment: Are you asking how to create time.Time for 24 hours in the past and in UTC, possibly truncating the hours? Or are you asking how to parse a timestamp string? Or how to filter records that stores the timestamp as a string?

Comment: I know how to create a timeStamp, but the time.Time object either uses time.Local or time.UTC which this value is neither.  So, when I am trying to limit the mongodb result set it appears that there are no records.  If the dates were stored as UTC or Local then it would be an easy solution.

How do I make mongodb ignore the time stamp when doing the $gte or $lt call is what I am looking for.

Comment: "Zulu Time Zone is often used in aviation and the military as another name for UTC +0". So effectively the dates you're seeing are UTC timestamp, the `Z` in the end indicates that this is what you have.

Comment: Ok, then what I am doing able should work right?  Why would it return 0 records, when if I dump them all I can clearly see records that are greater than the prior date at midnight?

Comment: maybe print your fromDate & toDate strings as well as the record you're seeing when dumping all. And try to make some reproducible example of how to create the initial data in MongoDB to be used in a test

Comment: I'll see what I can do to recreate the data, but I didn't initially create it so that will take me a little bit.

Comment: Thanks @baloo, I resolved the issue.  Looking back at the code I had already minimized the result set and thus excluded the records that fell into that date range.  I apologize for this post.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you're looking how to create a UTC timestamp 24 hours into the past where hours have been truncated?

You can try filtering on these dates:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    today := time.Now().Truncate(24*time.Hour).UTC()
    yesterday := today.Add(-24*time.Hour)
    fmt.Println(today)
    fmt.Println(yesterday)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that isn't quite what I am looking for.  I'm trying to figure out how to make mongo ignore the time stamp when running the date comparison query.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the above post actually works for the "Zulu" date time stamp.  This is a non-issue.